# How to identify if HTTP GET request is made by console/firebug/IE9 F12?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know if there is a way to identify is a HTTP request to a server is made through:

- the browser console
- JavaScript code running at client

I am able to make API calls to send like `getJSON`. Also I tried to make a Google Analytics call through the browser console.

Is there a way to find out if a request is made through the console, and if so can we block them at the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. An HTTP request is an HTTP request, there is no way to tell what the source was.

(Also, "the browser console" is just a way to trigger "JavaScript code running at client")

Comment: can't information in userAgent can describe  (sort of) who was sender ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir — That's an arbitrary string under the control of the client (and its *default* value will be the same for the two cases the OP specified in the question)

Comment: @quentin I agree with you, but is it not too open, I mean user may mess with anything by injecting a script. There can be scenarios like the way google analytics scripts are latched into webpages. So a bad user can pretty much mess with the google analytics scripts, there by messing the webpage. The effect may be even worse based on the reason the scripts are added.

Comment: @Quentin how about reading the caller stack. I see when a call is made via console an "eval" is executed atleast on webkit chrome.

Comment: @sudhanshu — And the client can extract all the data that would be sent and build the HTTP request manually, entirely bypassing any JS you write.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to detect this would be the user-agent header, but the header can be [changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29) by the client.

Comment: Exactly is this not too open for some scripts which can be at risk of bad user trying to make requests and mess databases.

Comment: Yes, this is why you shouldn't rely on the user-agent. Everyone can change it.
Requests thorugh the console can be changed to look exactly like a request through a browser.